# How do I say "as 引导倒装句" in English?

Tags: grammar

I want to search it in English.
I have tried google translation which translated it to "As Guided Inverted Sentences". I think it isn't right.

The word is "as 引导倒装句":

1. They go to concerts frequently, as do I.
2. She’s unusually tall, as are both her parents.

Comment: for more info see online dictionaries，e。
g。bkrs: **倒装句**  lg. inverted sentence, **倒装** lg.
1) be inverted (of word order)
2) invert the order of things
upside-down charging; upside down mounting (集成电路组装的)


 **引导** 1) v. guide; lead 引导代词
anticipatory pronoun 解释引导的分割
interpretation-guided segmentation

Comment: You know, "as 引导倒装句" is from English. I just want to know How English native speaker say it. :)
That is like 'sofa' is translated to Chinese as 沙发, then I want to know its original English is sofa rather than a directly pinying tanslation "shafa".

Comment: http://ask.yygrammar.com/q-4061.html has examples of 引导倒装句 which seem to show that it is used by Chinese grammars of English

Comment: English grammars explain the meaning and usage of these types of sentences, but it seems difficult to find any online English grammar with a name for this construction

Comment: Is it `to introduce inverted sentences`?

Comment: I honestly doubt there is any specific term that corresponds to this in English. The phenomena of "switching positions" in a sentence is called inversion, so you can probably say that's a sentence with invertion of auxilary-subject type (1) or verb-subject type (2).

Comment: Unexpectedly, It was asked by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverted sentence beginning with "As"